# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'mainlopp'

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Necesito ayuda para encontrar el error en mí código porque recién comienzo a usar python. Gracias

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
import socios

#------------------------------Pantalla Principal-----------------------------------------

class FormularioSocios:
    def __init__(self):
        self.socio1 = socios.Socios()
        self.ventana1 = tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title('Administración de Socios')
        self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)
        self.carga_socios()
        self.consulta_por_dni()
        self.listado_completo()
        self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row =0, padx =10, pady = 10)
        self.ventana1.mainlopp()

    def carga_socios(self):
        self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text = 'Carga de Socios')

        self.labelframe1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text = 'Socios')
        self.labelframe1.grid(column = 0, row= 0, padx = 5, pady = 10)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dni:')
        self.label1.grid(column =0, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.dnicarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydni = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.dnicarga)
        self.entrydni.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Nombre:')
        self.label2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.nombrecarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrynombre = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.nombrecarga)
        self.entrynombre.grid(column = 1, row =1, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Apellido:')
        self.label3.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.apellidocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryapellido = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.apellidocarga)
        self.entryapellido.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label4 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Sexo:')
        self.label4.grid(column = 0, row =3, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.sexocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrysexo = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.sexocarga)
        self.entrysexo.grid(column = 1, row = 3, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label5 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Fecha de Nacimiento:')
        self.label5.grid(column = 0, row =4, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.fechacarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryfecha = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.fechacarga)
        self.entryfecha.grid(column = 1, row = 4, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label6 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dirección:')
        self.label6.grid(column = 0, row =5, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.direccioncarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydireccion = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.direccioncarga)
        self.entrydireccion.grid(column = 1, row = 5, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label7 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Plan:')
        self.label7.grid(column = 0, row =6, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.plancarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryplan = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.plancarga)
        self.entryplan.grid(column = 1, row = 6, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label8 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Telefono:')
        self.label8.grid(column = 0, row =7, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.telefonocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrytelefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.telefonocarga)
        self.entrytelefono.grid(column = 1, row = 7, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label9 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Telefono:')
        self.label9.grid(column = 0, row =8, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.telefonocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrytelefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.telefonocarga)
        self.entrytelefono.grid(column = 1, row = 8, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Confirmar", command=self.agregar)
        self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=8, padx=4, pady=4)

    def agregar(self):
        datos = (self.dnicarga.get(), self.nombrecarga.get(), self.apellidocarga.get(), self.sexocarga.get(), self.fechacarga.get(), self.direccioncarga.get(), self.plancarga.get(), self.telefonocarga.get())
        self.socio1.alta(datos)
        mb.showinfo('Información', 'Los datos fueron cargados')
        self.dnicarga.set('')
        self.nombrecarga.set('')
        self.apellidocarga.set('')
        self.sexocarga.set('')
        self.fechacarga.set('')
        self.direccioncarga.set('')
        self.plancarga.set('')
        self.telefonocarga.set('')

    def consulta_por_dni(self):
        self.pagina2 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina2, text ='Consulta por Dni')
        self.labelframe1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina2, text = 'Socio')
        self.labelframe1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 5, pady =10)

        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dni:')
        self.label1.grid(column =0, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.dnicarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydni = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.dnicarga)
        self.entrydni.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Nombre:')
        self.label2.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.nombrecarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrynombre = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.nombrecarga)
        self.entrynombre.grid(column = 1, row =1, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Apellido:')
        self.label3.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.apellidocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryapellido = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.apellidocarga)
        self.entryapellido.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label4 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Sexo:')
        self.label4.grid(column = 0, row =3, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.sexocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrysexo = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.sexocarga)
        self.entrysexo.grid(column = 1, row = 3, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label5 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Fecha de Nacimiento:')
        self.label5.grid(column = 0, row =4, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.fechacarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryfecha = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.fechacarga)
        self.entryfecha.grid(column = 1, row = 4, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label6 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Dirección:')
        self.label6.grid(column = 0, row =5, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.direccioncarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrydireccion = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.direccioncarga)
        self.entrydireccion.grid(column = 1, row = 5, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label7 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Plan:')
        self.label7.grid(column = 0, row =6, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.plancarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryplan = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.plancarga)
        self.entryplan.grid(column = 1, row = 6, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label8 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Telefono:')
        self.label8.grid(column = 0, row =7, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.telefonocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrytelefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.telefonocarga)
        self.entrytelefono.grid(column = 1, row = 7, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.label9 = ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text = 'Telefono:')
        self.label9.grid(column = 0, row =8, padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.telefonocarga = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrytelefono = ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable = self.telefonocarga)
        self.entrytelefono.grid(column = 1, row = 8, padx = 4, pady = 4)

        self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text = 'Consultar', command = self.consultar)
        self.boton1.grid(column = 1, row = 8, padx = 4, pady = 4)

    def consultar(self):
        datos = (self.dnicarga.get(),)
        respuesta=self.socio1.consulta(datos)
        if len(respuesta)>0:
            self.dnicarga.set(respuesta[0][0])
            self.nombrecarga.set(respuesta[0][1])
        else:
            self.dnicarga.set('')
            self.nombrecarga.set('')
            mb.showinfo("Información", "No existe un artículo con dicho código")

    def listado_completo(self):
        self.pagina3 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina3, text = 'Listado Completo')
        self.labelframe1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina3, text = 'Socios')
        self.labelframe1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx =5, pady = 10)
        self.boton1 = ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text = 'Listado completo', command = self.listar)
        self.boton1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx =4, pady =4)
        self.scrolledtext1 = st.ScrolledText(self.labelframe1, width = 30, height = 10)
        self.scrolledtext1.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx =10, pady = 10)

    def listar(self):
        respuesta = self.socio1.recuperar_todos()
        self.scrolledtext1.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        for fila in respuesta:
            self.scrolledtext1.insert(tk.END,"código:"+str(fila[0])+"\ndni:"+fila[1]+"\nnombre:"+str(fila[2])+"\n\n")

aplicacion1 = FormularioSocios()

    import sqlite3

class Socios:

    def abrir(self):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect('database1.db')
        return conexion

    def alta(self, datos):
        cone = self.abrir()
        cursor = cone.cursor()
        sql = 'INSERT INTO CLIENTES(DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, SEXO, FECHA_NACIMIENTO, DIRECCION, PLAN, TELEFONO_CELULAR) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
        cursor.execute(sql, datos)
        cone.commit()
        cone.close()

    def consulta(self, datos):
        try:
            cone = self.abrir()
            cursor = cone.cursor()
            sql = 'SELECT DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, SEXO, FECHA_NACIMIENTO, DIRECCION, PLAN, TELEFONO_CELULAR WHERE DNI = ?'
            cursor.execute(sql, datos)
            return cursor.fetchall()
        finally:
            cone.close()

    def recuperar_todos(self):
        try:
            cone =self.abrir()
            cursor = cone.cursor()
            sql = 'SELECT DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, SEXO, FECHA_NACIMIENTO, DIRECCION, PLAN, TELEFONO_CELULAR FROM CLIENTES'
            cursor.execute(sql)
            return cursor.fetchall()
        finally:
            cone.close()
```

Comment: Typo: cambia `mainlopp` a `mainloop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu función `__init__` llamas `self.ventana1.mainlopp()` cuando debería ser `self.ventana1.mainloop()`. Puedes ver un ejemplo de usar [TKinter y Tk aqui.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program)

## Resultado

```py
def __init__(self):
        self.socio1 = socios.Socios()
        self.ventana1 = tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title('Administración de Socios')
        self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)
        self.carga_socios()
        self.consulta_por_dni()
        self.listado_completo()
        self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row =0, padx =10, pady = 10)
        self.ventana1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si, funciono.No podía encontrar el error. Muchas gracias!